# Kafka topic with very low retention time

Tags: apache-kafka

Are there any significant disadvantages when I set the retention time of a certain topic to lets say 10 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not have any disadvantage as such as it is a background process, but it should be known that in kafka partitions are split into segments. A new segment is rolled over when the configured time or size is reached.
kafka will not delete an active segment , so depending on your config and data load it may or may not delete a segment as desired.For the desired result please check  the below broker configs as well

1. Log retention check frequency - `offsets.retention.check.interval.ms`
2. Log retention time - `log.roll.ms`
3. `log.segment.delete.delay.ms`
4. Log cleaner configs